# Mystery service taking up huge amounts of memory and forcing CPU temperature up

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, temperature

This started yesterday when my PC died while I was using it reasonably intensively (running a newly released game). It wouldn't give me any video output or indication that it was even getting as far as the BIOS. I switched out the CPU for a spare and it worked, so I determined that the old CPU was fried. I'm still covered by warranty so a new one is on its way. Anyway, booting with the new cpu I noticed something strange: the core temperature was hovering around 70C while idling. I looked through process explorer and found an svchost process that was taking up 1.7-1.8 gb of memory. The information I have on it is as follows:

- Killing the process does not have any detectable effect on the system, other than the CPU temperature slowly decreasing back down to normal levels.
- It isn't there when I first boot up the system, it starts a good few minutes after booting.
- A full dump showed that it wasn't using anything outside of the system32 folder, and multiple virus/malware scans have given me nothing.
- It seems in some way associated with the windows update service, winupdate is the only entry I have ever seen listed inside it (as in, the nested list that appears when you click the plus beside it in process explorer), although sometimes it doesn't have anything listed at all.
- It doesn't ever use very much CPU, despite that being the component which is affected most, usually around 16-17% of what I have (system specs below)

The machine runs 100% fine after I kill it, which I have had to do every time I start it up (the alternative being to let my system run much hotter than I am comfortable with and risk BSOD while running intensive applications, which has happened once since my woes began, though no evidence to support that it was 100% related). I am out of ideas and getting sick of turning on my pc, watching the heat rise and then killing the process before resuming my usual activities. I also suspect that whatever this is may have been responsible for the death of my late fx6300, so I need some kind of solution before I let my new (courtesy of the AMD warranty dept.) processor anywhere near that motherboard.

**Specs**

- CPU: was AMD FX6300 6 core (RIP) now AMD phenom II x6 1090t
- RAM: 2x 4gb corsair (can't recall the exact model)
- GPU: ATI AMD Radeon HD 7700 1GB
- OS: Windows 7 professional N 64-bit SP1

Comment: Did you replace the thermal paste when installing the replacement CPU?

Comment: What does Process Explorer say the service name is? Right-click on the process, click Properties, click the Threads tab, sort by CPU usage with the highest on top, and see which threads are using significant CPU time and if they're associated with named services. If you've configured symbols in Process Explorer (this is highly recommended in all cases) the "start address" column in the Threads tab should be interesting too.